# Dplyr Version of ColSum or Dynamic Group_By in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm having a hard time working through something simple. I have a data frame where the first column is "Cat" and includes 3 different variables which I would like to group_by and summarize. Columns 2-5 are considered Months so 1 is the first month, 2 is the second month etc. What I'm trying to do is group_by Cat and sum up the individual columns. I've tried working with `colSums` and `aggregate`. Any help would greatly appreciated! Thanks

```
dff<-data.frame(Cat=c('A','B','C','A','A','A','B','C'),
               '1'=c(10,20,30,80,10,15,20,15),
               '2'=c(15,10,20,30,60,45,50,65),
               '3'=c(10,20,30,80,20,25,27,85),
               '4'=c(90,70,50,30,10,15,20,15),
               '5'=c(1,120,3,8,7,10,25,30))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `aggregate` in `base R`

```
aggregate(. ~ Cat, dff, sum)
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr) 
dff %>%
    group_by(Cat) %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), sum))
```